# QGIS 3 - default marker symbology

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, point, symbology, markers

Working with QGIS3 (QGIS 3.2.3)

Is it possible to change what the default point symbol is when adding a new point layer to a new project?

Context: I have to work with massive point layers very often. The first action in QGIS I always do is change remove the stroke from marker symbol (Simple marker -> stroke style -> no pen). Stroke width 0 or stroke color = fully transparent would work too. I also always change the marker size. It would save me a lot of time if the default could be changed.

Comment: Take a look in the project properties, I think you can change some default colours, not 100% sure about symbols though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the project properties, you may set a default for any symbol type there. You can also save the symbology to the data source, so when loading the layer again it already looks "correct".
[image]